# See mysql records that stored images

Tags: java, mysql

I stored an image to my mysql database and retrieve it correctly.

Now, if i have several stored images and want to see my records by statement:

```
Select * from images;
```

My system crushed and a lot of numbers fills the screen rapidly!

How can i do that?

My table:

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: I've never liked storing images directly in the database. I always prefer to store a path to the images, and have the image in a server side location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to only show the non-binary information when you retrieve each row.